# Find all working IPs on network wifi router ios

Tags: ios, networking

I am working on a project in which i need to get all the active IPs addresses on the network in xcode using objective c. If any one know how to get all these IPs then kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where have you been stuck during researching at?

Comment: Easy - If you know the gateway or main router address.. For Eg. 192.168.1.1.. then you can loop from 192.168.1.xxx from 1 to 255 and start pinging these devices.. if the device responds the ping then add it to the list of active devices..

Comment: @RenoJones, that is not necessarily true at all. Many PCs run firewall software which will not respond to ping.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an explicit reason you need to use objective-c and xcode? Perfectly good tools already exist to do this kind of work, such as [nmap](https://nmap.org).

If you absolutely have to use objective-c and xcode, look into [apples socket libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html). I am not an expert in objective-c, but your program flow would be pulling your current IP address and subnet, calculating how many possible hosts would be on your network, then use Apple's reachability classes to test every IP calculated and save which ones respond.

Comment: The reason, I imagine, is because he/she needs to report or record the IP in an application he/she is writing rather than getting it on the command line.